# When submitting a form, why does the eventhandler target all rows in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating a table that displays users appointments. These appointements when finished [ELSE], will give the opportunity for the user to give a rating [0-5].
But when I update the value using jquery, it updates all of the appointments that are finished instead of only the row(appointment) the user is targeting. Why is it targeting all of the appointments?

```js
let thisArray = []
let userId = $('#userId').val();
let marcacaoId = sessionStorage.getItem("marcacaoId");
console.log(marcacaoId);

$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/auth/marcacoesGET/' + userId,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    userId: userId
  },
  success: function(marcacao) {
    thisArray = marcacao
    buildTable(thisArray);
    console.log(thisArray)
  }
})

function buildTable(marcacao) {
  let table = document.getElementById('tabelaCliente')

  for (let i = 0; i < marcacao.length; i++) {

    if (marcacao[i].state == "Pendente") {
      let row = `<tr>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].address}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].date}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].hour}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].type}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].state}</td>
                 </tr>`
      table.innerHTML += row
    } else {
      let row = `<tr>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].address}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].date}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].hour}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].type}</td>
                     <td>${marcacao[i].state}</td>
                     <td>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 pl-lg-3">
                           <form action="/auth/avaliacaoPUT" method="POST" class="avaliacao">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <select id="projeto" name="aval_client" class="form-control-select">
                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary" onClick="window.location.reload()" onclick="javascript: form.action='/auth/avaliacaoPUT'">Submeter</button>
                             </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>`
      table.innerHTML += row

      $('.tabela-clientes').on('submit', '.avaliacao', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData2 = $(this).serialize();
        let formAction2 = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
          method: 'PUT',
          url: formAction2 + '/' + marcacao[i]._id,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: formData2,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

This is the backend logic as requested.

Router put

```
router.put('/avaliacaoPUT/:_id', authControllerMarcacao.clientAval);
```

Actual method

```
    exports.clientAval = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Client is giving rating to appointement...");
    console.log(req.params._id);
    try {
        const aval_client = await Marcacao.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, req.body, {useFindAndModify: false});
        console.log(req.body);
        await aval_client.save();
        res.status(200).json(aval_client);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({message: err})
    }
    console.log("Done!")
}
```

Comment: That depends on the backend logic; does it update all rows or does it only do one?. But I'm not seeing anything that links any row to an object in the `marcacao` dataset. Like an `id` or something. I see that you add the `$('.tabela-clientes').on('click')` event listener for every row, but you would only need one even listener for all forms. Use the `submit` event on all the forms instead of the `click` event on the buttons in the forms.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier thanks for the reply, it updates all rows, when it should be only updating the one appointment I want to give a rating. The id for each appointment was received when I made the get method for the first ajax call. The submit event didn't work also, since it is updating all of the appointments ratings. The backend function is receiving the marcacao id and updating the rating field.

Comment: Could you include the backend logic. That should be the part where it goes awry.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier there you go, thank you for going through this.

Comment: What is up with `onClick="window.location.reload()" onclick="javascript: form.action='/auth/avaliacaoPUT'"` on the submit button …?

Comment: @CBroe wym? is anything wrong?

Comment: Alright, backend seems solid. My theory now is that your event handlers causes all tables to be updated. So you're adding an event listener for each table, which all listen to a click in the `.avaliacao` form, which is every form. This causes one form to trigger all event listeners, each sending their own request with a preset ID. Check the network tab to see if multiple requests are being sent.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes! its sending 2 put requests for each appointment id to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in that you add an event listener for each row. Because each listener is firing whenever a form with the `.avaliacao` class is clicked, you will send a request for each form in the table.

Remove the event listener from the form and modify the output of the form.
Add the `marcacao[i]._id` value directly to the `action` of the form. This will ensure that the form will work without JavaScript.

Remove `onClick` and `onclick` attributes from the button. The former only works in React and the latter should not be used, as it is a very old of listening to event. Instead use the `addEventListener` or jQuery' `on` methods.

```
function buildTable(marcacao) {
  let table = document.getElementById('tabelaCliente')

  for (let i = 0; i < marcacao.length; i++) {

    if (marcacao[i].state == "Pendente") {
      let row = `
        <tr>
          <td>${marcacao[i].address}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].date}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].hour}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].type}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].state}</td>
        </tr>`

      table.innerHTML += row
    } else {
      let row = `
        <tr>
          <td>${marcacao[i].address}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].date}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].hour}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].type}</td>
          <td>${marcacao[i].state}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 pl-lg-3">
              <form action="/auth/avaliacaoPUT/${marcacao[i]._id}" method="POST" class="avaliacao">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <select id="projeto" name="aval_client" class="form-control-select">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary">Submeter</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>`

      table.innerHTML += row
    }
  }
}
```

You will only need one event listener. Place it outside of the `buildTable` function. Instead of `click`, listen to `submit`. The submit event is triggered whenever the a form is submitted. You can submit with multiple types of input, like pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> key or triggering it with JS, the submit event handles them all.

In there read the `action` of the trigger form --which is referenced with `e.target`-- and send the data to the server. Because the id is already present on the action you won't have to do any modifications to the `url` of the request.

```
$('.tabela-clientes').on('submit', '.avaliacao', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const $form = $(e.target);
  const formData = $form.serialize();
  const action = $form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: action,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly and very well explained!